# Is the basis of parity functions the only orthonormal basis for Boolean functions?

Tags: soft-question, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis

Is there another orthonormal basis of functions for Boolean functions? Or, more specifically, besides the parity functions, is there another explicit function (which is common and has a name) that can form an orthonormal basis for Boolean functions?

If not, why not?

Comment: A useful keyword: an orthonormal basis of Boolean functions in $n$ variables is essentially the same thing as an [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) of order $2^n$. (The standard basis of “parity functions” corresponds to the Sylvester/Walsh matrix.)

Comment: What @EmilJeřábek wrote and the answer by Mahdi assume that OP is looking for an orthonormal basis of the vector space of (real valued) functions on $\{-1, +1\}$ such that the basis functions themselves are boolean. Is this what the question is asking? Are the basis functions required to be boolean?

Comment: If the basis is not required to be Boolean, the question would be trivial: simply take any orthonormal basis for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think parities are the only orthonormal Boolean basis, for example [Paley basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_construction) provides a Boolean orthonormal basis in some cases. It's natural to ask if such bases, interpreted as Boolean functions, have any interesting applications.

Comment: Mahdi (or anyone else who is able), I would love to see (links to) concrete examples or relevant references.

Comment: You can just arrange any orthonormal basis as a $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix (one row per basis function, one column per evaluation point). This is an orthonormal matrix with (normalized) +1/-1 entries, and any such matrix is called a Hadamard matrix (as Emil also pointed out). Parities create Hadamard matrices, but there are other non-parity Hadamard matrices in some cases, such as Paley's construction above.